# show alert of java script on a same page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to show an alert of java script on a same i mean the below code

```
echo "<script type='text/jscript'>alert('Wrong Email!!.')</script>";
```

for example after checking the form if something wrong this message appear on the same page ,right now i can handle this message on a blank page & after that again with redirect code redirect to the same page ,but this is not the one which i want !!!
i want this message appear on the same page of P H P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the solution for this problem I,MYSELF.
we can send the submit values to another page but after checking in that page you can send back a value & result by query into the same page & show up the result ..look!

```
if($email=null){
```

echo ("document.location.href='../home.php?result=wrong';");
}

and on home page you can show the message like this !

```
if(isset($_GET['result'])){if($_GET['result']==wrong){ echo "<script
type='text/jscript'>alert('Wrong Email!!.')</script>";}}
```

That's it !!;)

Answer (score 1):

Use it in href:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Wrong Email!!.');">
```

Otherwise you need it in a Button, a.e. when the Form is Submitted:

```
function showAlert() {
    if(foo = bar)
        alert('Wrong eMail!');
}

<input type="submit" value="Click Here" onClick="showAlert();">
```

If you just want to see an Alert PopUp after Pageload, go with the HTML Body Tag and "onLoad".

Comment: you can check my idea on stack also ,look !when you press answer your own question the alert will pop up in the same page

Comment: SO uses the same basics, it's just another graphical form of alert(). Possibly something from JQuery, but i don't know in detail.